# How to add a flag based on a condition on previous rows in SAS

Tags: sas, lag, retain

I have the following data and would like to add a flag to each row if a condition is met in the previous row.

In the following data, I want a flag=1 if Cntr=S and only if the next row is FE followed by BC/ABC. I don't want 2/8/2019 observation for 101 and no data for 102 as there is no BC/ABC after FE.

Have:

```
   id   Date        Evt      Cntr
  101  2/2/2019      FE         
  101  2/3/2019      BC      S 
  101  2/4/2019      FE
  101  2/5/2019      BC
  101  2/6/2019      FE
  101  2/7/2019      ABC
  101  2/8/2019      FE
  102  2/2/2019      FE
```

Want:

```
   id   Date        Evt      Cntr       flag
  101  2/2/2019      FE         
  101  2/3/2019      BC      S 
  101  2/4/2019      FE                  1
  101  2/5/2019      BC                  1 
  101  2/6/2019      FE                  1
  101  2/7/2019      ABC                 1  
  101  2/8/2019      FE
  102  2/2/2019      FE
```

I tried using `lag` and `retain` functions to solve this problem but did not get what I wanted. Please help !!

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Please be more explicit in your description and/or give more examples of when to set the flag **and when not to set it**. For instance, what would happen if after the 7th row, there would follow two more rows for id `101` with Evt `FE` and `BC`?

Comment: Do I understand you well, you can only know you need to set the flag on the row with Evt `BC` or `ABC`, but that you have to set it on the preceding row with `FE` too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another case where DOW processing can compute the flagging state of a row.

Arrays can be used to track values in the group.  The arrays simplify computing the flagging of multiple regions after the `S`.  Choose an array size greater than the largest expected group size.

```
data have;
infile datalines missover;
attrib 
  id format=4. 
  date informat=mmddyy10. format=mmddyy10. 
  evt length=$3 
  cntr length=$1
;
input 
  id   Date        Evt      Cntr; datalines;
  101  2/2/2019      FE         
  101  2/3/2019      BC      S 
  101  2/4/2019      FE
  101  2/5/2019      BC
  101  2/6/2019      FE
  101  2/7/2019      ABC
  101  2/8/2019      FE
  102  2/2/2019      FE
  ;

data want;
  array evts[-1:1000] $3 _temporary_ ;
  array flags[1000] $1 _temporary_;

  call missing(of evts[*]);
  call missing(of flags[*]);

  do _n_ = 1 to dim(flags) until (last.id);

    set have;
    by id;

    evts[_n_] = evt;

    if cntr='S' then _s_index = _n_;

    if 0 < _s_index < _n_ - 1 then 
      if evt in ('BC', 'ABC') then 
        if evts[_n_-1] = 'FE' then 
          do ;
            flags[_n_] = '1';
            flags[_n_-1] = '1';
          end;
  end;

  if not last.id then do;
    put 'ERROR: ' id= 'group size larger than array size';
    stop;
  end;

  * apply flag value computed for each row of the group;
  do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
    set have;
    flag = flags[_n_];
    output;
  end;

  drop _:;
run;
```